# Master Data Service alternative

Tags: sql-server, master-data-management

I want an alternative for Master data services(**MDS**) which is not cloud based. Main agenda is to retrieve the data from **Microsoft SQL server** in excel format, make the changes in excel and upload it back to SQL server. Need a application with fronted which does that.
Kindly recommend. Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) about which StackExchange site is appropriate for this question. [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) will probably be the place to go.

Comment: We came across this which looks fantastic for quickly building database forms. It's thick client and there is a cost but it may help https://dbfront.com/